# python 2.4 execv hangs the process on AIX 5.1

Tags: python, fork, aix, execv

I am trying to fork a process using python 2.4 on AIX 5.1 , I am using the following code

```
def runcmd(cmd):

    (pid, fd) = pty.fork()
    argv = cmd.split()
    if not pid:
            print "In child process"
            #time.sleep(1) 
            os.execv(argv[0],argv)
            sys.exit()

    print "In parent process"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        print "In main"
        runcmd("/bin/sh cmd1 -l")
```

The problems is that this code hangs , it only prints "In main" and it just stays there locked. If , however I uncomment the line with "time.sleep(1)" it executed fine , it forks and everything is ok , it prints "In main" and then "In parent process" what it's supposed to do.

Out of my knowledge execv overwrites the image of the executing process and it does not return , but I cannot understand why this piece of code hangs on my machine. Please note that this code works fine with python 1.5 , why it doesn't on 2.4 is beyond me.

Can anyone help ? Is execv executing to fast and it messes up also the parent image (I know this sound silly by it seems that it's doing just that , or at least something similar to this)?

Thanks, Mircea

Comment: Does it behave the same when you use `os.fork` (since you're not actually using the PTY)?

Comment: can you test this on other OSs? Are you sure it is AIX specific? Good luck.

Comment: I have tested this in RH environments using the same python version and it behaves just fine , no hang whatsoever. I was able to repro this only on AIX machines ... very strange

Comment: And `os.fork` seems to be working just fine.